# How to read the txt file line by line and assign a variable to each line in jenkinsfile

Tags: arrays, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, devops

**I am passing the file as mytextfile.txt

test

yatin

deep

shubham

ankit

rohan

sachin

The pipeline fails with below error

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 11

at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)

at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)

at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1401.invoke(Unknown Source)**

```
  #!groovy

    pipeline {
      libraries {
         lib("library@master")
         }
        options {
          timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
            } 
          agent any 
        stages {
           stage('testing') {
            steps {
           script {
          checkout scm
          env.changefile = readTrusted('mytextfile.txt')
          lines = env.changefile.readLines()

          Detail = lines.get(1)
          Name = lines.get(3)
          Notes = lines.get(5)
          State = lines.get(7)
          Class = lines.get(9)
          Extras = lines.get(11)
          echo "detail used for this deployment is: ${Detail}"
          echo "name for this deployment is: ${Name}"
          echo "notes are: ${Notes}"
          echo "Class is: ${Class}"
          echo "extras is: ${Extras}"
          echo "State is: ${State}"

             }
           } 
         }
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arrays in java/groovy have zero-based indexes.

so, if you have `11` elements in `lines` array

then to get the first one use `lines.get(0)` or `lines[0]`

to get the last one use `lines.get(10)` or `lines[10]` or `line[-1]`

Comment: I have tried the same way in the pipeline using lines.get() but the build fails with the error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 11

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 11` means you still try to call lines.get(11) when you have only 11 elements in an array. for the array with `11` elements the last one will have index `10`!

Comment: as a general comment on what it seems like your trying to do. if your deployment file was json or yaml then you could load them in as a Map structure via the readJSON and readYAML jenkins steps and not have to rely on specific lines